# create menu type effect

Tags: iphone

I need how to create menu type effect.

for example
here is the Main Button, when click on Main Button it should be visible it's subcategory, once click on Main button it's should be hidden.

Main Button.
 |-Main button1

Thank you,

Comment: Some basic questions:
1) What kind of language in what environment?
2) Please post a code sample, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to implement menus in iPhone OS is to use a Navigation Controller. You can read about it in [the View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)'s chapter on [Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingNavigationControllers/UsingNavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1).